# Boost Spirit: How to serialize qi::grammar and qi::rule objects?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost-spirit-qi

I'm using Boost library version 1.55.

## 1st Question

I have the following object `myRule`:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::blank_type>     Rule;

Rule myRule %= qi::string("Hello world");
```

How can I serialize it as a string object?

## 2nd Question

I have the following object `myGrammar`:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::blank_type>     Rule;
typedef qi::grammar<std::string::iterator, qi::blank_type>  Grammar;    

class MyGrammar : Grammar
{
     // Constructor/Destructor
     MyGrammar()::base_type(myRule)
     {
         myRule %= qi::string("Hello world");
     }
     ~MyGrammar() { }

     // Attributes
     Rule myRule;
};

MyGrammar myGrammar;
```

How can I serialize it as a string object?

Comment: Any advise accepted :P !

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm looking into this now...

Comment: Sorry but it was 4 years ago I don't remember exactly. I think I would have written the solution here if I had found it at the time. I'll try to retrieve the project I was working on to see if I can give you some clues, but don't expect too much ^^

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thanks for looking into it again.